# ActiveRecord::Relation - how to know if pending insert?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

given

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base

end

p = Parent.first
c = p.children.build()
```

How can test if p.children has any pending inserts without triggering loading the association? If I check p.children.present? it will load the association.

Rails 3.2

Notes to help clarify:
By "pending" I mean the in-memory, not yet persisted objects. I would like to know (and iterate) over any of these not-yet-persisted objects without loading the association. Essentially, if I call find_or_initialize_by... it only looks at the db. I'm trying to check if there are any yet-to-be persisted records that I can update instead of another insert.

Comment: What do you think is a "pending insert"? There's no such thing in Rails. If you're trying to tell whether there are any records which are currently instantiated but not persisted, there is no built-in way of doing this, because it's not a thing you should need to do during the course of building a Rails application. You'll have to keep track of this state yourself, but you should probably also post your actual problem. Needing to know whether you've built an object without saving it isn't something you should have to do, there's probably a better solution.

Comment: yes, new record that is instantiated, not yet persisted. Let me noodle on simplifying the example.

Comment: You should maintain the list of new records separately if you want to iterate over them. Using `p.children` for this purpose is an abuse of what that member *is*. The whole point of accessing it is to load records from the database.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do it without loading the association.  You may wish to reconsider your line of thinking. Why is it that you want to check for pending inserts?

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood build. It's just an alias of new, nothing special. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/959fb8ea651fa6638aaa7caced20d921ca2ea5c1/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L84

Build won't "create" or make pending insert, of record in database, just create a new object in memory so that the view can take this object and display something, especially for a form.

Those kind of objects can be later saved, but it's not necessary to do that.

Comment: right, an in-memory new record _but_ the association knows about it. If I iterate over p.children it will include the in-memory record that is not persisted yet.

Comment: Yes, it knows because that new record has id of parent, and both (parent and association record) are in memory in that step. If you reload parent record you should not see built association instance.